# Androidx Material TextInput color doesn't change

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I'm trying to create a `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` aka `TextInputLayout` in my application and make hint text change its color depending on the presence of the text in the field. 
Right now code for this element looks like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_email_text_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_email_hint"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.78"
            android:textColorHighlight="#FF00FF"
            android:textColorHint="#00FF00"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_email_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I'm applying a style

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

But this style only applies to the hint color when it's inactive and it applies the same color (`android:textColorHint`) to both states of the hint - when it fills the textField and when it jumps to a corner.
When the TextInput receives focus, the label changes color to a `colorAccent` color from the THEME, not from the style I applied

My question is - how can I make hint label change color depending on the presence of text (not on TextInput being focused or not) using XML only? I've seen examples of people doing so before (on support libraries) but I couldn't achieve such a result myself.

Answer (score 0):

> Same issue faced while migrate to AndroidX.
>   Change parent theme

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Try removing the parent as it is not required.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi: Yea without parent it's working. thanks

Comment: Tried to use your parent theme parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox". Still doesn't work as I want it to work. Nothing changes when I remove parent theme completely

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The issue is with com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alphaXX. Issue was resolved by reverting to com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.

Side note: I can't even inflate a layout which contains TextInputLayout when using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08. 1.1.0 seems to be full of problems.